# Exception thrown in Tomcat when using JSF in Eclipse Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, tomcat7

I'm trying to set up a web project in Eclipse (Indigo SR1) on MacOSX with:
Tomcat 7.0.22
JSF 2.0

It is a Dynamic Web Project where I've added the JSF Project Facet through Project Properties.

When adding the JSF Project Facet I get to choose from using either: Mojarra 2.0.3 or Apache MyFaces 2.0.2

If I choose Mojarra and try to start the Tomcat (from within Eclipse) I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()
```

If I choose MyFaces I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
```

Based on other answers here I have no jar:s added to the WEB-INF/lib folder and in the project's build path only the Libraries included by Eclipse itself are added:

- Apache Tomcat v7.0
- EclipseLink 2.3.0
- JSF 2.0 (Apache MyFaces JSF Core-2.0 API 2.0.2)
- MySQL JDBC Driver

The project itself is minimal and contains two xhtml-files but yet no beans.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> *If I choose Mojarra and try to start the Tomcat (from within Eclipse) I get the following exception:*
>
> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()

This exception suggests that you've a JSP API/impl JAR file of a different servletcontainer make/version in the webapp's runtime classpath which conflicts with the JSP API of the target runtime itself.

---

> *If I choose MyFaces I get the following exception:*
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

This exception suggests that you've a JSF impl JAR file of a different JSF make/version elsewhere in the webapp's runtime classpath which conflicts with the JSF impl actually being loaded.

---

Both exceptions boil down to that the webapp's runtime classpath is dirty. Apart from `/WEB-INF/lib` folder -which seems to be empty, as you said- the `Tomcat/lib`, `JRE/lib` and `JRE/lib/ext` are covered by the webapp's runtime classpath. You should ensure that you have **not** added any JARs in there yourself. Remove them, if any. Remove/uninstall/reinstall if necessary Tomcat and/or JRE to be on the safe side. You should then untouch their libraries, unless you really understand what you're doing.

I *think* that you've a `javaee.jar` from Glassfish server somewhere in your webapp's runtime classpath. That would at least explain the *both* exceptions as it includes both the standard JSP API and Mojarra API.

Comment: Still no success. I have a clean install of Tomcat, I've never tampered with the JRE/lib or JRE/lib/ext. When Eclipse builds and publish the project it puts the following in wtpwebapps/JSFTest/WEB-INF/lib/: com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar
com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201004141950.jar
eclipselink.jar
el-ri-1.0.jar
javax.activation_1.1.0.jar
javax.mail_1.4.0.jar
javax.persistence_2.0.3.jar
javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201005080402.jar
javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar
jsf-api-2.1.0-b03.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl-2.1.0-b03.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar